# PHP get_class error converting SimpleXML to array

Tags: php

I have the following function which returns a SimpleXML object into a normal array. It seems to work fine, however if I turn error reporting on then I get lots of warnings say:

```
Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given
```

But it still seems to be working somehow. Any ideas how I can get it to work without the errors?

```
function convert($content){
    $data = (array)$content;

    foreach ($data as $k => $v){
        if(strpos(get_class($v),"SimpleXML")!==false){
            $data[$k] = XMLArray($v);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to test if ``$v`` actually holds an object, or an array or a string.

Comment: Learn to use SimpleXML and you don't need to do any of this!

Comment: @NigelRen how do you use SimpleXML to make the output a simple array that I can use. Currently I am using $xml = simplexml_load_string($content); but this loads data into an array that isn't a basic array and I cannot use it to directly reference certain keys etc.

Comment: Have a look through http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php.  If you still have problems, add the XML to the question and someone will post a simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add is_object check. You are getting a warning because it is running in a loop. for some value of $v it is an object and that part is running fine but for some value $v is not an object. You are getting warning in those cases when $v is not an object.

```
     function convert($content){
    $data = (array)$content;

    foreach ($data as $k => $v){
        if(is_object($v) && strpos(get_class($v),"SimpleXML")!==false){
            $data[$k] = XMLArray($v);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it because of you are passing `$v` instead of `$k`

```
function convert($content){
    $data = (array)$content;

    foreach ($data as $k ){
        if(strpos(get_class($k),"SimpleXML")!==false){
            $data[$k] = XMLArray($k);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

check this

Comment: Not working, it completely stops working with this and lots of errors.

Comment: function convert($content){
    $data = (array)$content;
    $new_Data=array();

    foreach ($data as $k ){
        if(strpos(get_class($k),"SimpleXML")!==false){
            $new_Data[]= XMLArray($k);
        }
    }

    return $new_Data;
}

Comment: Still not working, same errors but the array gets messed up.